# Do enemies always spawn in the same locations?

Tags: ape-out

When I play through a level in Ape Out, will enemies always spawn in the same locations? For example, if an explosive enemy spawns north of the start of the map on one run, will they spawn there when I play the map again? Or are the spawn locations random?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the enemy locations and the map layout is randomized on each attempt.

I tested this by walking down until I found my first enemy. When I attempted to retrace the same path after respawning I discovered the rooms were arranged differently.